# Deploying Django project to Heroku

Tags: django, heroku

I am new to Heroku and Django and I have some issue with deploying the app to Heroku.
git: https://github.com/garden117/recipe-app-api

My gut feeling is that it's something to do with Profile, I tried different options: paste in different folders/rename the app, still doesn't work.

log:
2020-07-03T19:50:15.208779+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=cryptic-atoll-79106.herokuapp.com request_id=3feed318-fe5b-4dd6-9135-259c590c8098 fwd="45.49.181.247" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

Comment: Your Procfile should be in the root folder of your application and not in the app

Comment: thanks Hendrik for you reply. I moved a procfile one directory up. Then there was another error that wsgi module is not found, so I updated procfile: web: gunicorn app.app.wsgi:app --log-file -. After that I got different error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app.settings'. So I changed wsgy.py and put there os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'app.app.settings'). After that I got another error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'core'. I feel like there is should another way to update the path for all the files

Answer (score 0):

```
git init
git remote add origin master 'Heroki URL'
git add --all
git commit -m 'First Push'
git push -u origin master
or if not work do this
git push --force origin master
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply. But even second step returns error: git add origin master 'https://cryptic-atoll-79106.herokuapp.com/'
fatal: pathspec 'origin' did not match any files.   And it seems like code is there on Heroku, I can see all the files via bash

Answer (score 0):

web: gunicorn --chdir app app.wsgi:application --log-file -